# Item Tree not being populated from link selector in Sitecore 10.3

Tags: sitecore, content-editor

Whenever we try to add a link, we get the empty Sitecore Items tree in the dialog window:
[image]

The tree list only shows the top level /sitecore and nothing else. There is nothing in the log to give any indication of what might be wrong.

Sitecore 10.3.1 upgrade from 10.0.3.

Comment: Any javascript errors? And what is the result of ajax call which is executed when you try to expand the tree?

Comment: @MarekMusielak, When the dialog opens, the tree is already expanded, as in the pic. There are no errors in the console log at all. When I collapse and expand again, I see no change at all in the network tab of dev tools. I clicked to list view and back to tree view and I saw a call to /sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog (200). The response contains the HTML for the dialog box/modal.

Comment: And if you try to collapse and expand again?

Comment: @MarekMusielak Nothing changes.It behaves the same as before I switched to list view.